# avoid a page being added to browser history when redirecting using a meta http-equiv tag

Tags: html, http, web

I have a web page, that redirects to the desired destination url using:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=$destination.url" />
```

I would like to avoid the first page being in the browser history.

In particular, in mobiles (Android, iOS, etc) I would like the back button to skip the redirecting page.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your two options are to either use a real HTTP redirect, or to use JavaScript's `location.replace`.

The former is better, but if there's some reason you can't do it, `location.replace` can work as an alternative:

```
document.location.replace(redirectURL)
```

`location.replace` actually replaces the current location in the browser history, so the back button will not go back to the redirection page. If you do this you may also want to include a meta refresh with a short timeout as a fallback if you expect any of your users to not have JavaScript.

Comment: S3 with CloudFront in front makes HTTP redirects quite challenging. If you have any advice on how to do that, please do send it along.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

If you want to redirect, use an HTTP redirect. `<meta>` redirects have many flaws, and this is one of them.

Comment: S3 with CloudFront in front makes HTTP redirects quite challenging. If you have any advice on how to do that, please do send it along.

Comment: @Costa — If you have a new question, then [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).