# Redirect with JavaScript but without affecting the history

Tags: javascript

I'm doing `window.location = 'redirect-to';` in a page, but when the user presses the back button, it just lands on the redirect, doing effectively nothing.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [avoid a page being added to browser history when redirecting using a meta http-equiv tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980021/avoid-a-page-being-added-to-browser-history-when-redirecting-using-a-meta-http-e)

Comment: Have you looked at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window.location.replace(url)` when you don't want to affect history (like a server redirect).

Use `window.location = url` when you want to affect history.